# How to embed a video in MailChimp?

Tags: html, css, html-email

I am new to HTML/CSS basics and am trying to embed a video in MailChimp but I met a problem.

When I used the code block in MailChimp to embed a YouTube video like this:

`<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ABRwvcAtRNk" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

it showed on the screen. However, when I previewed the email, the video just wouldn't show up.
I wonder where the problem is and how I can embed a video using MailChimp.

Answer (score 1):

`<iframe>` are usually not well supported in email clients. It looks like Mailchimp has a specific Video content block to insert videos in emails: https://mailchimp.com/en/help/add-video-to-a-campaign/

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't find the official instructions before. By the way, would you mind suggesting some tags that are suitable for email clients so that the video can be played directly? The video content block in Mailchimp often leads to a new browser window..

Comment: Actual `<video>` support directly in email clients is very poor (see https://www.caniemail.com/features/html-video/). On top of that, I don't think platforms like Youtube or Vimeo actually offer a `<video>` implementation (as far as I know you must always use their `<iframe>` implementation).